# express.js socket pooling

Tags: node.js, express

Based on the [suggestion  on improving node.js performance](http://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile) and especially no. 2 "turn off socket pooling", how can this be set in express.js?

Answer (score 2):

That suggestion is for the Node HTTP client API. Express is just a server library. If you're using http.request, you'd adjust the socket pooling the same way she describes.

Comment: Ok. But do i do that. I need to allow more open sockets. Is this a configuration?

Comment: There is no way i can do thing on srcer side?

Comment: @Cristian: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking. What is it you want to do?